# How to configure Spring Controller and/or JAXB to help prevent SQL / XSS injection

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, xss

I have a Controller in Spring with a method like the following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/something", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/xml")
@Valid
public void something(@RequestBody final SomeBody myDto  . . . . .
```

I want to be sure that the Request Body does not contain any SQL or Javascript characters to help avoid SQL Injection, XSS attacks etc.

Does JAXB already handle that scenario? 
I was considering writing a filter but I can only read the request body once?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't do the SQL injection prevention at that level. JDBC already has a lot of prevention mechanisms with `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: OK but what about Javascript injection (XSS) attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper XSS and SQL injection protection (and data validation in general) can only happen on the server side. Client side validation is irrelevant as a malicious user can just write their own client or send custom HTTP request. Client side validation is only useful to notify non-malicious users of form validations without a server round trip (ex: verify that a field is a number or email address). Even in that situation the server must also perform the validation.

To prevent SQL injection use bind variables (eg prepared statements) for *all* parameterized queries. You should never have to concatenate client inputs to generate a SQL statement. If you never generate SQL statements from client input and only use them as bind variables you don't have to worry about SQL injection at all.

```
String clientValue = ...
Connection conn = ...
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepare("INSERT INTO foobar VALUES (?)");
stmt.setString(clientValue);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Or with Spring JDBC:

```
String clientValue = ...
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = ...
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO foobar VALUES (?)", clientValue);
```

To prevent XSS make sure to sanitize all data before you *output* it. White-listing client data when it is saved is generally a good idea too if you have an explicit subset of acceptable text but it becomes more complicated when you factor in Unicode support. It's generally much easier to just deal with it on the rendering side.

For example if you are using JSTL to render your output you would use something like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
${fn:escapeXml(myModelVariable)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Filters` to clean your forms. It will fetch all your request attributes and clean them all. Another option is to use `JSoup` API's. visit following links to know more.

[JSoup XSS Api's](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

[Filter approach to prevent XSS threat](http://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/)

**EDIT :**

Read OWASP sheets to know how to avoid XSS and SQL injection.

[OWASP - prevention of XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

[OWASP - prevention of SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

Take a look at [HDIV](http://hdiv.org/) which integrates with spring 3.1, it has out-of-the-box support for XSS, CSRF, Data Integrity Checks.

Answer (score 1):

For XSS attacks are mostly client side hack.For every user input you can actually sanitize the input data using encoding so that it takes out all the special characters. The basic way to handle on client side is to use the Javascript escape() function.   OWASP is a good refernce to go thru the lon list of client side hacks.  For Server side hacks to prevent SQL injection you can look at using Prepared statements or using template based query creation (QueryDSL) or HQL etc.